# Does all $f^{(a)}=0$ for all $0\leq a \leq n$ imply $\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

The title is pretty self explanatory:

Does all $f^{(a)}(0)=0$ for all $0\leq a \leq n$ imply $\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n}=0$?

Here $f^{(n)}$ is the $n$-th derivative and I define $f^{(0)}=f$. This comes motivated from a proof I read where this holds but all the $f^{(a)}$ must exist in some interval around $0$ (they used the mean value theorem), I wondered if this was true even if all the $f^{(a)}$ are defined but only on $0$.

Intuitively I'd guess this is true, since the derivative is a linear transformation after all; however I had no luck with this and couldn't find any counterexample.

Comment: That is not true. Consider $f(x)=x^n$. Maybe you mean $a\leq n$?

Comment: yes my bad will correct rn

Comment: By Taylor's formula, if $f(0)=f'(0)=\ldots = f^{(n)}(0) = 0$, then $f(x) = o(x^n)$ at $0$, which is exactly what you ask

Comment: Ok, but what means $f^{(j)}(0)$ if $f^{(j-1)}$ is not defined in a nbhd of $0$? Are do you mean to only relax this for $f^{(n)}$?

Comment: With $n=0$, the assumption is only that $f(0)=0$, whereas the claim is $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. This need not be valid unless $f$ is continuous at $0$

Answer (score 1):

If
$$f(0)=f'(0)=...=f^{(n)}(0)=0$$

then, by Taylor-Young formula,
for $ x $ closer to zero,

$$f(x)=0+0+...+0+x^{n}\epsilon(x)$$

and if $ x\ne 0 $,

$$\frac{f(x)}{x^n}=\epsilon(x)$$
So, we can say that the limit is zero.

Comment: Hey, just a heads up, the question got edited so this no longer applies. ($0 < a < n$ was replaced with $0 < a \leq n$)

Comment: @StephenDonovan Ok, now the limit is zero.

Comment: I think your edit wasn't quite complete. It should be $x^{n+1}\epsilon,$ shouldn't it?

Comment: @StephenDonovan No, that is for Taylor-Lagrange. I used Taylor-Young.

Comment: Understood, my apologies

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not now Taylor-Young formula, could you link me to some resource where I can find it?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know how to give a link but you can just Google it.

Comment: I have, but all I've found assume there's some open interval around 0, which I don't.

Comment: @Shiranai If $ f $ is differentiable at $ 0 $, then it is continuous at $ 0$, so the function is defined around zero.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I don't think this is true. For example if the domain is $(-1,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ then one can check that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ but not defined in any open interval around it.

Comment: @Shiranai How do you define $ f'(0) $.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah just the usual limit, only extra requirement is that the domain of the derivative must be accumulation points of the domain of the original function.

Comment: @Shiranai I recognize your question is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If we add the assumption (as you did, editing the question) that all the $n$ derivatives (not only $(n-1)$) are zero, then it holds indeed:

$$\lim _{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n}= \lim _{x \to 0} C\frac{f^{(n+1)}x^{n+1}}{x^n} = \lim _{x \to 0} C f^{(n+1)}x =0 $$

Comment: Hey, just a heads up, the question was edited to match your suggestion. You may want to edit your answer accordingly